# All trajectories of a dynamical systems converges to $0$

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems

I've been struggling with solving the following system:

$\dot x = -x+xy$

$\dot y = x-y -x^2-y^3$

I already know that the only fixed point is $(0,0)$ and I also know that the system is exponentially stable(calculating the Jacobian). But what I really want to know is: do all trajectories of this system converges to $0$?

What can I do to prove that? Is it enough to create a Lyapunov function? What exactly means that it is asymptotically stable in a Lyapunov sense?

Thanks so much. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the Lyapunov function $V(x,y) = \frac{1}{2}(x^2+y^2)$. For a Lyapunov function $V$, $\dot{V}<0$ for $(x,y)\neq0$ implies that the dynamical system is asymptotically stable. In this case, we have
$$
\dot{V} = x\dot{x}+y\dot{y} = -x^2+xy-y^2-y^4.
$$
You can use basic calculus to show that $\dot{V}(x,y)$ has a global maximum at $(x,y)=0$, (take the gradient and set equal to 0). We also have $\dot{V}(0,0) = 0$, so $\dot{V}<0$ for $(x,y)\neq0$ and the system is asymptotically stable

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but, the fact that we can find a lyapunov function for the origin (0,0), means that all trajectories converges to (0,0), right? If we had a liapunov function for (z,w), means that all trajectories converge to (z,w)?

Comment: Yes. In the literature you will typically find Lyapunov functions defined with the origin in mind but this is because you can apply a change of variables to move any critical point to the origin

Comment: To show that the system is **globally** asymptotically stable, it's important to also point out that your Lyapunov function tends to infinity at infinity (which it does in this case). See this question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2472608/system-with-a-lyapunov-function-over-mathbbrn-but-not-globally-asymptotica