# can global stability be inferred by the unique existence of stable equilibrium?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems

For N-dimensional dynamical systems, if we know there only exist one stable equilibrium (but whether it is global or local is not yet proved), can we infer, the stable equilibrium is globally stable?

Thank you in advance for any response!

Comment: You will need extra conditions on the to infer the global stability such as the existence of a global Lyapunov function or that the system is contractive.

Comment: @KBS Thanks a lot! About inferring global stability via contractive property, could you recommend some materials?

Comment: @KBS And I think for gradient system, global stability can be inferred by the unique existence of stable equilibrium point.

Comment: Gradient systems are quite restrictive in general so unless you specifically work with them, this will not be very useful. For contraction analysis, you can check the seminal works by Lohmiller and Slotine. And more recently the works on incremental stability and p-dominance analysis (see e.g. Sepulchre and Forni).

Comment: @KBS Thanks a lot for sharing!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nope. There is a counterexample in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2472608/system-with-a-lyapunov-function-over-mathbbrn-but-not-globally-asymptotica/2474778#2474778):
$$
\dot x = x \, \frac{3 x^2 y^2 - 1}{x^2 y^2 + 1}
,\qquad
\dot y = -y
.
$$
The only equilibrium is $(x,y)=(0,0)$, and it's locally but *not* globally stable. (See that other answer for details.)